# inserting unicode character set data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, unicode

I am using mysql server configuration details are:

```
"protocol_version   10"
"version    6.0.0-alpha-community-nt-debug"
"version_comment    MySQL Community Server (GPL)"
"version_compile_machine    ia32"
"version_compile_os Win32"
```

I am using hibernate for working with application running over chinese character set. In this server I am not able to find the utf8mb4 character set in the list of CHARACTER_SET.

In hibernate I am using below configuration settings:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutordb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8mb4</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8mb4</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.verifyServerCertificate">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.requireSSL">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useSSL">false</property>
```

But is is saying like utf8mb4 character set is not supported. with utf8 it is working perfectly but not able to add chinese charaters unicode in database says invalid charaters.

Where I am wrong. I donot know. Can you provide mysqlserver essential link that can provide me the utf8mb4 support. Or any other issue with my code over here.

IF I am missing some snippet from pasting over here. please confirm so I get the correct solution with this.

Comment: I am getting correct values from front UI jsf components. but I am trying to insert unicode chars in database but not able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 6.0 was never released.  It was abandoned about a decade ago.  Instead, install 5.5.3 or newer.  (Suggest at least the latest 5.6.)  And consider going with a 64-bit version if your hardware *and* OS are already 64-bit.  (32-bit is OK, but limiting, especially in today's bigger RAMs.)

If Hibernate is loading MySQL "for you", then perhaps it is years out of date and needs updating.

Comment: I have done lot of search over internet but not found the real msi for 32 bit. Can you provide the link about it. above configuration details were fetched using version query of mysql

Comment: The first Download button on http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html#downloads

Comment: Is there any driver issue with this. I am using 5.1.38 mysql driver set. is this ok. This issue is making failure for my project. Plz can you help.

Comment: Drivers rarely need to change, so I would _guess_ that it would work.

Comment: I have added answer for this question thanks to you to bcoz it was not going to work without your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have resolve this with help of Rick James (Thanks to you too).

I have modified default setting of unicode support instead of passing encoding parameters with hibernate.cfg.xml.

added below line to my.cnf or my.ini or my-default.ini:

character_set_server=utf8mb4

Restart the database server/mysql service using service mysqld restart

if you are going to pass encoding utf8mb4 with hibernate config, then not supported exception will be thrown while accessing database.

Thanks to all